# Restore to Windows 10

Tags: operating-systems, recovery

Can anyone help me with how I can restore My latest upgraded Windows 11 to Windows 10?

I have a lot of data that I can't afford to lose. So unable to formate it.

Can someone have any solution to restore my OS to Windows 10 without formating my system?

Comment: Golden Rule: never perform any major upgrade without a solid, tested backup to which you can revert.

Comment: If it’s been more than 10 days there is no way to revert the upgrade other than a clean install

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks.  I edited my post to 10 days.  I had read a while back the Microsoft might extend this, but as of now they have not. Thanks again.

Comment: You can extend the amount of time but it has to be changed before 10 days. Windows will automatically cleanup the previous version

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded within the last 10 days, go to Start, Settings, Update and choose Recovery Options.

In Recovery Options, you can roll back to Windows 10 and not lose anything.

If beyond the Recovery Days (check for recent changes as to the number of days allowed for Windows 11 Roll back), then you need to completely back up your system and reinstall Windows 10 and recover your data.

Let us hope the Roll Back works for you.